# SharePoint 2013 Lunch Menu Order

Tags: 2013, survey

So I have a project to automate our lunch ordering system into SharePoint. The idea of the system is that an email shall be sent to all the the employees of the company. The email will take them to the link in SharePoint where it shows the lunch menu for next week. The employees will only have 2 choices for each of the 5 days in the next week and must choose for each day. It is basically like a survey, but the questions must change every week because the menu each week will change.

How do I do this in SharePoint?

[image: Here is How I picture the idea]

Answer (score 0):

I guess someone will have to enter the weekly menus anyway, so why don't you save the survey as a template that will be created every week by the user who is entering the menu. 
The survey should have a workflow that sends the link it's to by e-mail to all employees to answer. The workflow would be triggered once the options are added.

Comment: If I save the survey as a template, wouldn't that make a lot of apps in the site contents when months have passed and surveys are crated each week?